# How to use a variable with existential type where a concrete type is required?

Tags: scala, types, existential-type

This contrived example illustrates the essence of my problem:

```
trait Producer[X] {def make(): X }

sealed trait MyProducer[X] extends Producer[X]
case class MyProducerA(n: Int) extends MyProducer[Int] {...}
case class MyProducerB(s: String) extends MyProducer[String] {...}

def doWithProducer[P <: Producer[_]](producer: P): P = {
  makePair(producer) // the compiler fails to infer the type parameter
  producer
}

def makePair[X](p: Producer[X]): (X, X) = (p.make(), p.make())

// this is how I need to call the method
val myProducer: MyProducer[_] = ???
doWithProducer(myProducer)
```

The `doWithProducer()` method cannot have a type parameter for the product type since the subtypes of `MyProducer` have different product types (or am I already wrong here?). Inside `doWithProduct()` I know that I have a concrete instance of a Producer that has a type parameter. I don't care which but it has one. However, the compiler can't figure this out.

Can I solve this problem without changing the method signatures?

**Update:** What I find curious and what leads me to assume there has to be a way is that I can actually capture the type of the product indirectly in a type variable:

```
def duplicate[X](p: X): (X, X) = (p, p)

duplicate(producer.make)
```

However, I still fail to get to a `Producer[X]`.

Answer (score 2):

`P <: Producer[_]` means that `P` is a producer of some **unknown** type. You shouldn't use existential type if you want to say that `P` is a producer of some **known** type to be inferred.

Try

```
def doWithProducer[X, P <: Producer[X]](producer: P): P = {
  makePair(producer)
  producer
}
```

or

```
def makePair(p: Producer[_]): (Any, Any) = (p.make(), p.make())
```

You have to change signature of at least one of methods `doWithProducer`, `makePair` to make them compile.

Or you can cast

```
def doWithProducer[P <: Producer[_]](producer: P): P = {
  makePair(producer.asInstanceOf[Producer[Any]]) 
  producer
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Casting to `Any` works for me, although I'd like to avoid a cast if possible. I cannot change the signature of `doWithProducer` since the subclasses of `MyProducer` produce different types and I need `MyProducer[_]` to refer to this particular trait. At least I found no other way to express the type that comprises all the subtypes of `MyProducer`.

Comment: @lex82 "I cannot change the signature of `doWithProducer` since the subclasses of `MyProducer` produce different types"  I don't understand why you can't use `doWithProducer[X, P <: Producer[X]]`.

Comment: Then the compiler fails at the `doWithProducer` call. The `Producer` is invariant in its type argument (and it has to be because the real-world problem that I simplified here, requires it). That's why a `Producer[Any]` is not what I want (but what would make the call possible). Instances of `MyProducer` are in general not subtypes of `Producer[Any]`.

Comment: @lex82 "Then the compiler fails at the `doWithProducer` call. " Do you mean that `doWithProducer` call fails if you try `doWithProducer[X, P <: Producer[X]]`? What's the error? Don't use existential types since they are irrelevant to your purpose (you want type to be inferred).

Comment: The problem is just pushed up one level. I cannot pass a `Producer[_]` to a function expecting a `P <: Producer[X]`. In my example above, which type should the `X` bind to? It's neither `String`, `Int` nor `Any`. A `Producer` is either a `Producer[String]` or a `Producer[Int]` but even with union types I could not pass a `Producer[String | Int]` because the type parameter is invariant and no subtype of such a type exists in my code.

Comment: This is the error: inferred type arguments [Nothing,MyProducer[_$1]] do not conform to method doWithProducer's type parameter bounds [X,P <: Producer[X]]

Comment: @lex82 Compiler just didn't infer type. 
`val myProducer: MyProducer[Int] = ???`
  `doWithProducer[Int, MyProducer[Int]](myProducer)`
  `val myProducer1: MyProducer[String] = ???`
  `doWithProducer[String, MyProducer[String]](myProducer1)`

Comment: @lex82 If you don't want to specify second type parameter, you can do standard "partial application" trick: `def doWithProducer[X] = new Helper[X]` `class Helper[X] {
    def apply[P <: Producer[X]](producer: P): P = {
      makePair(producer);
      producer
    }
  }`
`val myProducer: MyProducer[Int] = ???`
  `doWithProducer[Int].apply(myProducer)`

Comment: it's not so much that I don't want type parameters. I think I can't use them for `doWithProducer()` if I want to be able to pass in a variable of which I (and the compiler) only know it is a subtype of `MyProducer`, i.e. a `MyProducer[_]`. The signature looks like this: `def doWithProducer[P <: Producer[_]](producer: P)`. So I don't see how I can apply your trick.

Comment: A little bit of background: the producers are actually messages sent to actors, so the type `MyProducer[_]` is the protocol of the (typed) actor, i.e., all messages it accepts. It can't have a type parameter, because the actor doesn't have one. It just accepts `MyProducer[_]` messages regardless of the type. Accepting `MyProducer[X]` would mean I have an `ActorRef[Producer[X]]` for some `X`. But there is only one actor and it accepts all types. I hope this helps.

Comment: @lex82 Either you can use type `MyProducer[X]` and then you can expect that `X` is inferred or you can use only `MyProducer[_]` and then you shouldn't expect type inference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191928/discussion-between-lex82-and-dmytro-mitin).